# Trigger to update a linked server name record when specific values are enterred in status

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, linked-server

Database Sql server 2008R

I'm synchronizing two separate database applications. The databases are linked servers. One is a CRM and one is an ERP. When the user enters one of two code strings in the Names table Status column of the CRM, the Names table record of the ERP needs to be updated with the name record from the CRM.

VN=Vendor
CO=Contact

**CRM**

```
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
| Names | Table | ContactID | TypeID | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Status |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
```

User enters (1 of 2 codes) VN, CO in Status

**ERP**

```
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
| Names | Table | ContactID | TypeID | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

The name record from the CRM needs to update the name record of the ERP

It seems like it would be something like:

```
UPDATE n
    case i.Status
        when 'WO' then SET ERP.FirstName = i.FirstName, ERP.MiddleName = i.MiddleName, ERP.LastName = i.LastName
from inserted I
        when 'PN' then SET ERP.FirstName = i.FirstName, ERP.MiddleName = i.MiddleName, ERP.LastName = i.LastName
     end
from inserted i
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Names n on n.CompanyID = i.CompanyID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. This is not how a case expression works. A case expression is used to control the value of a single column. You need to update multiple columns. Taking the code I posted in your previous question on this topic you just needed to add the three new columns like this.

```
UPDATE p
SET Status = 
    case i.Status when 'CN' then'Converted'
        when 'WO' then 'Working'
        when 'PN' then 'Pending'
    end
    , FirstName = i.FirstName
    , MiddleName = i.MiddleName
    , LastName = i.LastName
from inserted i
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Projects p on p.ProjectID = i.QuoteID
```

--EDIT--

Based on your recent comments I thinking that maybe you want something along these lines. Notice the else predicate in the case expression has been added.

```
UPDATE p
SET Status = 
    case i.Status when 'CN' then'Converted'
        when 'WO' then 'Working'
        when 'PN' then 'Pending'
        else p.Status
    end
    , FirstName = i.FirstName
    , MiddleName = i.MiddleName
    , LastName = i.LastName
from inserted i
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Projects p on p.ProjectID = i.QuoteID
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. The name record only needs to update when the user has enterred VN or CO in the status column. Is there a way to add that to the query?

Comment: Ummm...if you want to happen only when the values are VN or CO what do you expect for the status? You should be able to modify the code easily enough to accommodate two different values.

Comment: I can picture how to update the name record with several columns, but if the case if for only updating one coloumn, maybe it is that it would be two different begin, end blocks .   UPDATE name
SET name.FirstName = inserted.FirstName, 
name.MiddleName = inserted.MiddleName, name.LastName = inserted.LastName
...
FROM inserted, name
WHERE inserted.contactid= name.contactid AND inserted.status = 'VN' OR inserted.status = 'CO'

Comment: Not really sure what you mean here. It seems you need some additional logic I just don't know what you need. Aside from that you really should get in the habit of using explicit joins instead of a comma separated list of tables. It is just too easy to make a mistake doing that. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Maybe you just need to add an else to the case expression so that if the inserted status is anything other than CN, WO or PN you simply set the status to p.Status (meaning it wouldn't change)?